# Ubuntu 8.04 vs Ubuntu 10.10 for 256 ram server

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, ubuntu-8.04

What is better for small vps? What will be the problems, if go with old version? That would be a LAMP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old version Ubuntu 8.04 LTS will give you much older packages e.g. Apache 2.2.8, PHP 5.2.4, MySQL 5.0.51.
A newer version will have more recent / newer packages (doh!).

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS instead of 8.04 will also be a reasonable choice, for it has long term support, so longer than 10.10 or 11.04 (up until 2015 - see image courtesy of Wikipedia --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_timeline):

[image]